# I cant get my animation to work properly with transition.to

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am relatively new to Corona and am still unsure whether I understand `transition.to`, so please bear with me and be specific. I have an object that is "floating" (gravity is set to (0, -4)) up on the screen. So it's a "dynamic" physics body, and it interacts properly with all other physics bodies. Collision listeners are working perfectly. However, when the object, a balloon, reaches a Y of 150, I want the object to transition to a lower location on the screen in 250ms. But when I run my code, the balloon goes to random points on the screen and is inconsistent.

```
    local function move(event)

       If (balloon.y <= 150) then
          transition.to(balloon, {time = 250, x = balloon.x, y = 320);
       end
    end


    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", move);
```

I've read that since the `enterFrame` listener is called every 30-60ms, transitions that take longer than that will basically call the function repeatedly, never allowing the transition to complete. If that is the problem,, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to prevent duplicate calls, put a flag `isInTransition` (this is arbitrary)  onto the `balloon` and check for its status for every call.

```
local function move(event)

    if not balloon.isInTransition then
        if (balloon.y <= 150) then
            transition.to(balloon, {time = 250, x = balloon.x, y = 320)
            balloon.isInTransition=true
        elseif balloon.y == 320 then
            balloon.isInTransition=nil
        end
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", move);
```

Physics does not work well with transitions if there are physics interactions (e.g. collision) mixed with `transition.to()`.

If you wanted the balloon to move to lower location without collisions, you can try `balloon.isSensor=true/false`.

Discussion [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2010/11/08/changing-collision-filters-after-physics-object-created#comment-29733) about a case similar to yours.